# Check visibility row

Tags: asp.net

I have a GridView

```
  <asp:GridView ID="Grid2"  runat="server" AllowSorting="true"  OnRowDataBound = "OnRowDataBound" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" AllowRowSelect="False"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"  DataSourceID="DBu" AllowPaging="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="matr" HeaderText="id" SortExpression="matr"></asp:BoundField>
         <asp:BoundField  DataField="datediff1" HeaderText="Difference" SortExpression="datediff1"> </asp:BoundField> 
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server"  ID="DBu"  ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>' SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"   SelectCommand="stored" > 
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

with some row not visible setted by JS function that contain the following istruction  `row.style['display'] = 'none';`

The result is that I have some row as this

```
<tr style="display: none;">
```

I want in the Code Behid check the "display"attribute for each row in gridview. I tried this

```
GridView grdxport = Grid2;
        foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in Grid2.Rows)
        {
            if (grdxport.Rows[gvrow.RowIndex].Style["display"] == "none")
            { 
                //do something
            }
        }
```

but it doesn't work.
How can I do to check this attribute?
Thanks!

Comment: _"setted by JS function"_ then it's not possible to read this value at serverside because the server doesn't know that the row is invisible at clientside

Comment: That will never work. Changes you make to the page with javascript will not be send to the server. So as far the server is concerned those properties do not exist.

Comment: ok! So it is not possible to check a CSS style from Code Behind?